# how to orderBy string date? CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, jpa

How can I `orderBy` string date correctly(in date format) using Criteria builder? because the stored date in my model was string.

My model:

> @Column(name = "date_time")
>
> private String dateTime;

When I try to query it.

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = JPA.em().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<T> cq = cb.createQuery(Pickup.class);
    Root<T> root = cq.from(Pickup.class);
    CriteriaQuery<T> all = cq.select(root);

    cq.orderBy(cb.desc(root.get("dateTime")));
```

I got wrong order, how can I make my string date to date format then orderBy it? I'm very new to it, Can someone help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't store dates as strings.

Comment: But It has a large amount of data and changing it to date format may cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YOURPATTERN");
CriteriaBuilder cb = JPA.em().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<T> cq = cb.createQuery(Pickup.class);
Root<T> root = cq.from(Pickup.class);
CriteriaQuery<T> all = cq.select(root);
cq.orderBy(cb.desc(dateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(root.get("dateTime"))));
```

You can convert the dateTimeString to a DateTime with the DateTimeFormatter.

Comment: Does this really work? root.get("dateTime") and dateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime() has different return types.